# Downloading Dependences From Private Amazon S3 Repository with Gradle

Tags: groovy, amazon-s3, gradle, dependency-management, build.gradle

I am looking to add Groovy support to an existing java project so that I can seemlessly compile mixed Java and Groovy code using invokedynamic so that I can get [Java-like execution speed without needing to waste excessive amounts of time with verbose Java syntax](http://groovy.codehaus.org/InvokeDynamic+support)

After reading that the gmaven plugin no longer supports compilation -and that the groovy eclipse compiler plugin [doesn't yet support invokedynamic](http://groovy-eclipse-plugin.42567.n3.nabble.com/groovy-eclipse-compiler-for-Maven-and-Invoke-Dynamic-support-td4025232.html), I asked myself, why would I want to continue using Maven if it compiles Groovy code that is needlessly slow?

Consequently, I decided I would try scrapping maven for Gradle so that I could obtain faster code while also porting some python deployment scripts to Gradle tasks so as to only need one codebase.

I have some libraries stored on a simple password protected s3 maven repository (in order to avoid needing enterprise overkill like artifactory). After doing some basic research, I have found that Gradle has no  built in support for adding in custom dependency management as determined by [this stack overlow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20453233/custom-dependency-management-plugin-in-gradle) and [this support forums post](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/use_custom_protocol_transport_for_gradle_artifact_repo).

I did manage to find a [s3 plugin for gradle](https://github.com/literalice/gradle-aws-s3-sync) -but it doesn't deal with management of dependencies.

If the whole point of Gradle is to be more flexible than Maven and if the core purpose of a dependency management/ build system is to effectively manage dependencies from a variety of sources-then lack of support for custom repositories appears to be a fairly significant significant design flaw which makes any issues I have encounted with Maven thus far pale in comparison.

However, it is quite possible that I am missing something, and I have already invested several hours learning Gradle -so I figured I would see if there is some reasonable way to emulate dependency management for these s3 dependencies until Gradle developers fix this critical issue. Otherwise I will have to conclude that I am better off just using Maven and tolerating slower Groovy code until the compiler plugin supports invokedynamic.

Basically I need a solution that does the following:

1. Downloads dependencies and transitive dependencies to the gradle cache
2. Doesn't require me to hardcode the path to the gradle cache -so that my build script is platform independent.
3. Doesn't download the dependencies again if they are already in the cache.
4. Works with a multi-module project.

However, I cannot find anything in the documentation that would even give me a clue as to where to begin:

Answer (score 2):

[Gradle 2.4 has native support for S3 repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/release-notes#support-for-amazon-web-services-s3-backed-repositories). Both downloading dependencies and publishing artifacts.

To download with IAM credentials (paraphrased from the link above):

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "s3://someS3Bucket/path/to/repo/root"
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey 'access key'
            secretKey 'secret key'
        }
    }
}
```

Then specify your dependencies as usual.

Comment: I am using this exactly this way and as a bonus, I also deploy (install) artifacts to S3: http://sm4.github.io/build/2015/07/16/hosting-a-maven-repository-in-amazon-s3/

Comment: That link is to the latest release notes, not 2.4. Here is the correct link: https://docs.gradle.org/2.4/release-notes.html#support-for-amazon-web-services-s3-backed-repositories

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any custom repository support to make this work. Just declare a `maven` repository with the correct URL. If the repository works when used from Maven, it will also work with Gradle. (Uploading may be a different matter.)

Comment: It's a private s3 repository, so I have to use the s3:// protocol. It only works in maven through a specific build extension: <build>
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.springframework.build.aws</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.springframework.build.aws.maven</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
</build>

Comment: So you left out the most important bit of information. :-) AFAIK, it's not currently possible to add custom repository support to Gradle by way of a plugin. PS: I wouldn't take for granted that invokedynamic Groovy is much faster than standard Groovy on current JVMs.

Comment: Is support in the works, or is it likely something that won't be available for years?

Comment: I can't make any predictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use S3 and http

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    ivy {
        url "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my-bucket"
        layout "pattern", {
            artifact "[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"
            m2compatible = true
        }
    }
}
```

Name the jar in S3 to name-rev.jar (joda-time-3.2.jar) in my-bucket.
Also upload a pom file.
And in S3 give all permission to Download the jar and pom.