# Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available, private Amazon S3 Maven repository

Tags: android, maven, amazon-s3, dependencies, build.gradle

After following this guide,

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Building-your-own-Android-library#setting-up-a-private-amazon-s3-maven-repository

when i run `./gradlew uploadArchives`

it returns

```
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadArchives'.
Could not publish configuration 'archives'
Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository remote (s3://XXX) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
```

i can build the aar with `./gradlew build`

i have also looked at

[Downloading Dependences From Private Amazon S3 Repository with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23447954/downloading-dependences-from-private-amazon-s3-repository-with-gradle)

https://github.com/wbinglee/maven-s3-repo

i can upload my aar file via the command line, using the keys and s3 bucket.

my gradle.properties

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY="xxx"
AWS_SECRET_KEY="xxx"
POM_NAME=HighwayZodiac
POM_ARTIFACT_ID=library
POM_PACKAGING=aar
VERSION_NAME=1.01-SNAPSHOT
VERSION_CODE=1.01
GROUP=app.crasoftsystems.highwayzodiac
POM_DESCRIPTION="A simple add two operand library repo."
```

my build.grade (module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/gradle-mvn-push.gradle')

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "app.crasoftsystems.highwayzodiac"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    libraryVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def outputFile = output.outputFile
            if (outputFile != null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.aar')) {
                def fileName = "${archivesBaseName}-highway.aar"
                output.outputFile = new File(outputFile.parent, fileName)
                output.outputFile = new File("pathtoaar", fileName)
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
}
```

my build.grade (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven{
            url "s3://xxx"
            credentials(AwsCredentials) {
                accessKey AWS_ACCESS_KEY
                secretKey AWS_SECRET_KEY
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

./gradlew --stacktrace uploadArchives

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository remote (s3://XXXX-androidlib) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:uploadArchives'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:66)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.PublishException: Could not publish configuration 'archives'
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:66)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:228)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:221)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:621)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:604)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository remote (s3://XXXX-androidlib) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.AbstractMavenPublishAction.publish(AbstractMavenPublishAction.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.MavenDeployAction.publish(MavenDeployAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.AbstractMavenResolver.execute(AbstractMavenResolver.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.AbstractMavenResolver.publish(AbstractMavenResolver.java:82)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.BaseMavenDeployer.publish(BaseMavenDeployer.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.publish(DefaultIvyDependencyPublisher.java:45)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher$1.execute(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:56)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.publish(IvyBackedArtifactPublisher.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload.upload(Upload.java:64)
        ... 68 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository remote (s3://XXXX-androidlib) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:235)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:211)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:443)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.MavenDeployAction.publishArtifacts(MavenDeployAction.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.action.AbstractMavenPublishAction.publish(AbstractMavenPublishAction.java:94)
        ... 81 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: No connector available to access repository remote (s3://XXXX-androidlib) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:400)
        at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:231)
        ... 85 more
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message. I tried to publish in my local maven. The mistake i did is not setting the maven repo path properly.

In project parent build.gradle file I put as below,

```
  java.util.Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('maven-repo.properties').newDataInputStream())
project.ext.repository = properties.getProperty('repo')
```

Created a file named "maven-repo.properties" in my project folder and was setting repo path like , file:////Users/myusername/.m2/repository , but in above parent build.gradle file, I was parsing some property named "repo" from "maven-repo.properties" file, that's why it couldn't connect to my maven repo. Then, I set it in maven-repo.properties file like "repo=file:////Users/myusername/.m2/repository" , then the error is fixed.

Please, check your maven repo path, where you are publishing.